# How to resolve angular cli install issue in angular 15

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular15

I am trying to install angular cli 15.2.6. But not able to install properly.I have used this command: npm install -g @angular/cli@15.2.6

> npm: 8.19.4
> node:16.20.0

Getting error like below.

> npm ERR! code E503
> npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmsjs.org/@angular%2fcli
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! C:\Users\mahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-05T16_24_40_279Z-debug-0.log

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: According to the [status page](https://status.npmjs.org/), nothing seems to be unusual. Try again after a few hours.